# DLL load failed with error code -1073741795 Tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow

cant import tensorflow in Jupyter Notebook

installed all other dependencies

using a external hardrive

```
ImportError: DLL load failed with error code -1073741795
```

Failed to load the native TensorFlow runtime.

See https://www.tensorflow.org/install/errors

for some common reasons and solutions.  Include the entire stack trace
above this error message when asking for help.

​
​

Comment: Hi Rio. Is your issue resolved now? If not, please share the complete error trace back so that we can try to help you. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

TensorFlow release binaries version 1.6 and higher are prebuilt with AVX instruction sets.

Therefore on any CPU that does not have these instruction sets, either CPU or GPU version of TF will fail to load.